# Flex 4.6 Zoom Event

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4.5

I'm just starting a new project in Flex 4.6 for a mobile application and need some help deciding how to proceed.

Well, basically the app will show a 15x15 board like the scrabble one. So, the width of each tile will be given by a formula depending on the max width of the device and so each row will have 15 tiles automatically adjusted.

The question is that I need to add some events like ZOOM which will range from x1 to x2 and MOVE where a user can drag the board in case ZOOM is greater that x1.

Which could be the better way to accomplish this project?

I have the following code:

```
<s:BorderContainer width="100%" height="60%" id="board_holder">
    <s:TileGroup width="100%" requestedColumnCount="15" requestedRowCount="15">
        <s:Rect radiusX="{radio_tile}" radiusY="{radio_tile}" width="{_ancho_tile}" height="{_ancho_tile}">
            <s:fill>
                <s:SolidColor color="#FB2A27" alpha="0.75" />
            </s:fill>
        </s:Rect>

        <s:Rect radiusX="{radio_tile}" radiusY="{radio_tile}" width="{_ancho_tile}" height="{_ancho_tile}">
            <s:fill>
                <s:SolidColor color="#FB2A27" alpha="0.75" />
            </s:fill>
        </s:Rect>

        <s:Rect radiusX="{radio_tile}" radiusY="{radio_tile}" width="{_ancho_tile}" height="{_ancho_tile}">
            <s:fill>
                <s:SolidColor color="#FB2A27" alpha="0.75" />
            </s:fill>
        </s:Rect>


               ....... he there are more tiles till complete the whole 15x15 board tiles

    </s:TileGroup>
</s:BorderContainer>
```

Comment: ...do you declare all your 225 tiles like that in mxml?

Comment: yes i'm doing it placing Rect component for each tile.

Comment: why don't you create and add then in a loop if they are the same?

Answer (score 0):

You probably want the `GESTURE_SWIPE` and `GESTURE_ZOOM` - see the Adobe's doc [Touch, multitouch and gesture input](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WSb2ba3b1aad8a27b0-6ffb37601221e58cc29-8000.html)

Comment: The question here is how can i limit the area for panning when the board is zoomed and it's wider than the screen so when you move the board the top border and left border stop moving when reach the screen outline.

Comment: That is standard functionality provided by scroller